# start_epoch = global_step // numBatch ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I don't know the reason for this error, so I ask for help online. Please forgive my original code is so rough, because I am just a beginner.

During debugging, I got an error on this line:

```
start_epoch = global_step // numBatch
```

The error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Here is my code:

```
def train(self, train_low_data, train_high_data, eval_low_data, batch_size, patch_size, epoch, lr, sample_dir, ckpt_dir, eval_every_epoch, train_phase):
    assert len(train_low_data) == len(train_high_data)
    numBatch = len(train_low_data) // int(batch_size)

    # load pretrained model
    if train_phase == "Decom":
        train_op = self.train_op_Decom
        train_loss = self.loss_Decom
        saver = self.saver_Decom
    elif train_phase == "Relight":
        train_op = self.train_op_Relight
        train_loss = self.loss_Relight
        saver = self.saver_Relight

    load_model_status, global_step = self.load(saver, ckpt_dir)
    if load_model_status:
        iter_num = global_step
        start_epoch = global_step // numBatch
        start_step = global_step % numBatch
        print("[*] Model restore success!")
    else:
        iter_num = 0
        start_epoch = 0
        start_step = 0
        print("[*] Not find pretrained model!")

   print("[*] Start training for phase %s, with start epoch %d start iter %d : " % (train_phase, start_epoch, iter_num))
```

Comment: Can you add a line print(numBatch) before " #load pretrained model ".
To check the value of numBatch.

Answer (score 0):

That's likely because you're dividing by zero.

numBatch is zero, which means that train_low_data is probably zero.

You should verify that before running the function, because it is meaningless if you have nothing to train on. I added another assert for you to do that in the start of the function:

```
def train(self, train_low_data, train_high_data, eval_low_data, batch_size, patch_size, epoch, lr, sample_dir, ckpt_dir, eval_every_epoch, train_phase):
    assert len(train_low_data) > 0
    assert len(train_low_data) == len(train_high_data)
    numBatch = len(train_low_data) // int(batch_size)

    # load pretrained model
    if train_phase == "Decom":
        train_op = self.train_op_Decom
        train_loss = self.loss_Decom
        saver = self.saver_Decom
    elif train_phase == "Relight":
        train_op = self.train_op_Relight
        train_loss = self.loss_Relight
        saver = self.saver_Relight

    load_model_status, global_step = self.load(saver, ckpt_dir)
    if load_model_status:
        iter_num = global_step
        start_epoch = global_step // numBatch
        start_step = global_step % numBatch
        print("[*] Model restore success!")
    else:
        iter_num = 0
        start_epoch = 0
        start_step = 0
        print("[*] Not find pretrained model!")

print("[*] Start training for phase %s, with start epoch %d start iter %d : " % (train_phase, start_epoch, iter_num))
```